# The syntax about While loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm practicing the While Loop in Ruby and got a basic example as below

```
i = 3
while i > 0 do
  print i
  i -= 1
end
```

My question is why I can't interchange do..end with {} as if I rewrite the above code as below it doesn't work anymore

```
i = 3
while i > 0 {
  print i
  i -= 1
}
```

However, it seems to work without the first "do"

```
i = 3
while i > 0 
  print i
  i -= 1
end
```

Could anyone explain the rule or redirect me to the right resource? Thx!

Comment: Note: You can also express this as `3.downto(1) { |i| print i }`

Answer (score 2):

As you said `do` is optional for while loop. `While keyword` is enough to define a block which is finished with end like any other block in ruby. In addition, `end` is mandatory for while block.

If you want to use while on just one line you can do such as below:

```
    i = 0
    i += 1 while i < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

While mandatory needs `end` in Ruby.

[Syntax example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops)

`do` is optional and can be omitted.

So, it is not the case where pair `do - end` can be replaced with `{}`

Comment: Thanks that clarifies my confusion and the link you provided is really useful